# Rerender scroll page to top

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm rerendering a part of my page after an ajax call. But it causes the page to scroll up. How I can prevent the page scrolling on partial rerender.

Thanks

Comment: Share your code that is causing the problem

Comment: This is only happening if the rendered area is too long which causes the page to be to long.

Comment: No way to help you if you don't help us to understand your problem.